# Многопоточность в java8

Tags: java, многопоточность

Я пытаюсь понять, почему этот код работает, по идее при массовом добавлении чисел в коллекцию и при одновременном  удалении должно  упасть. Говорю сразу, многопоточность только учу.

```
public class TwoThread {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    Convect convect = new Convect();
    TreeSet<Integer> numbers = new TreeSet<>();
    Object lock = new Object();
    Object lock2 = new Object();

    public static void main(String... args) throws InstantiationException,
            IllegalAccessException {

        /*
         * one two three four five six seven
         */

        TwoThread m = new TwoThread();
        m.make();

    }

    void addNumber() {
        synchronized (lock) {
            try {
                while (true) {
                    numbers.add(convect.toNumber(br.readLine()));
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    void removeNumber() {
        synchronized (lock2) {
            while (true) {
                try {
                    if (numbers.size() != 0) {
                        int i = numbers.first();
                        numbers.remove(i);
                        System.out.println(i);
                    }
                    Thread.sleep(5000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    void make() {
        Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                addNumber();
            }
        });

        Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                removeNumber();
            }
        });

        /*
         * try { t1.join(); t2.join(); } catch (InterruptedException e) {
         * e.printStackTrace(); }
         */

        t1.start();
        t2.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: У вас происходит неявная синхронизация через чтение с терминала и `Thread.sleep`. Не надо так делать.

Comment: Значит плохо проверял, привели проверку.

Comment: Thread.sleep я использую в виде таймера, доступ к коллекции для удаления элементов должен быть каждые пять секунд